I'm calling the Cloud Billing API and I'm getting a 403 error
I have enabled the Cloud Billing API service, then created a service account and set the permissions
Billing Account Usage Commitment Recommender Admin, then I send my code, which returns error 403.
The following is the error returned：

raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting
https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com/v1/billingAccounts/XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX?alt=json
returned "The caller does not have permission". Details: "The caller
does not have permission">

from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# Set service account file path
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = './1.json'

# Create credentials
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE)

# Build service object
service = build('cloudbilling', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

# Your billing account ID can be found in the Google Cloud Billing console
billing_account_id = 'billingAccounts/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'

# Get billing information
billing_info = service.billingAccounts().get(name=billing_account_id).execute()

print('Billing Account Info:')
print(billing_info)

# Get a list of bill items
projects = service.billingAccounts().projects().list(name=billing_account_id).execute()

print('Projects:')
for project in projects.get('projectBillingInfo', []):
    print(f"{project['projectId']}: {project['billingAccountName']}")

I tried many times and there was no problem with the permissions! How can I call it

It's unclear which IAM role(s) you're assigning to your Service Account but evidently, you're using an incorrect set. See the list of Cloud Billing roles and grep by billing.accounts.get and pick the minimal role that includes that permission e.g. roles/billing.user

Google provides a Cloud Client library for Cloud Billing which would be preferable to the API Client Library that you're using.

You would be wise to consider using Application Default Credentials to simplify and improve the resilience of your code. For the API Client Library that you're using, you can then simply credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()

The Billing Account has its own IAM system. See this document: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/grant-access-to-billing There are three systems to manage: Google Cloud, Cloud Billing, and Payments. Each one has their own user management system.
